# How to create a "one-liner" for oracle that includes "set" commands as well as sql statements

Tags: oracle

I want to execute a dynamic sql containing some set commands. Is it possible to do so without embedding newlines?

```
set heading off ; set lines 1000 ; select * from my_table;
```

Note the above does not work due to the semicolons between the set commands:

```
SP2-0158: unknown SET option ";"'
```

**Update**  The whole point of this question is to do it *on one line*.

Comment: The `set` commands are only meaningful to SQL*Plus and would mean nothing - and be invalid - in a dynamic SQL statement, even if run on their own. They are client commands, dynamic (or indeed static) SQL is run on the server. What you're asking doesn't really make sense - you have to do something with the results of the dynamic SQL, and even in SQL*Plus the `set` wouldn't change anything unless you were selecting into a ref cursor and then printing that.

Comment: This is not true: i am updating the question.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the term 'dynamic SQL' in the way [it is normally meant](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm). You might need to explain the context then, including where this is submitted from - looks like a shell script maybe?

Comment: Of course, the SP2 error code should have been a bit of a giveaway... Anyway, you could consider putting the `set` commands in a [user profile `login.sql` file](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#i1133106), perhaps. But it still depends how you're running your command, and to some extent why you don't want embedded new lines - whether that rules our a heredoc approach, for example, if this is from a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I have found for my own purposes is to put my standard SET commands in a file called sql_settings.txt in a directory with an environment variable holding its path and another variable for the connect string:

```
sqlsets=/directory/where/sql_settings/stored/sql_settings.txt
db_conn=<ConnectStr>
```

& then execute a one-liner as such with a shell here-string:

```
sqlplus -s $db_conn @$sqlsets <<< "select * from my_table;" | less
```

(The "less" pipe will prevent from cluttering your shell session)

You could also get fancy and create a shell function to minimize typing to the SQL query:

```
function mydb { sqlplus -s $db_conn @$sqlsets <<< "$@;" ; }
```

Then call as such:

```
mydb 'select * from my_table;'
```

Answer (score 0):

`set` command is a directive for sqlplus and is not related to `sql` and you can do it this way

`set heading off lines 1000 
select * from my_table;`

Comment: to do it in one-line is not possible because you need one line for sqlplus settings another line for the sql statement

Comment: or you can put everything in a separate file, and call it in your script like @do_everything_bla_bla, but it is a different story

Answer (score 0):

After extensive research, I have concluded this is not possible to perform with oracle.